# GIMP clone tool CTRL+CLICK doesn't work when ubuntu show mouse position is selected

Tags: 12.04, gimp

IN GIMP 2.8, I can't select clone source with **CTRL+CLICK** when "**show mouse position with CTRL** selected on in Ubuntu system configuration".

I post here because I spent a lot of time trying to understand and no info was found over Internet.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. If you posted a question and found the answer later, you should 1) post your solution as an answer (and not as part of the question), 2) accept your answer (unless there is a better answer). If you do not do those steps, others will think that you are still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**, when "show mouse position on Control" uncommented under system configuration.